# Hibernate :Save Parent automatically before saving Child

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a parent-child relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public final class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer userID;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "admin")
    private Set<News> news;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "news")
public final class News
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int newsID;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID")
    private User admin;

    @Column(name = "newsText")
    private String newsText;

    @Column(name = "dateOfPost")
    private Date dateOfPost;
}
```

Here `User` is the parent and `News` is the child. The reason that I have the cascade operations such is because I want all `News` objects to be deleted/persisted when I delete/persist the corresponding `User`. Also when I persist a `News` object I want the corresponding `User` to be persisted [but not deleted if the `News` is deleted]. I have a service method that saves a `News` object as follows:

```
User u = new User("administrator");
News n = new News("News text");
n.setUser(u);       
u.addNews(n);

session.save(n);
```

For the above code I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.maximus.db.model.News]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at com.maximus.db.dao.NewsDAOImpl.addNews(NewsDAOImpl.java:17)
    at com.maximus.db.service.NewsServiceImpl.addNews(NewsServiceImpl.java:31)
    at com.maximus.test.db.service.NewsServiceTest.testAddNewsWithNewUser(NewsServiceTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'userId' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2327)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2312)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 38 more
```

What could be the issue here?

Am I incorrect in having a service method that tries to save a child? Should I always save the parent instead?

Thanks.

UPDATE: If I instead save the user as `session.save(u)` instead of the news, everything is fine. So the question that remains is, is it incorrect to save the child instead of the parent? If not, then how do I achieve it?

Comment: did you try **session.save(u)** instead?

Comment: @ManuPK If I use `session.save(u)` then everything is fine. I am asking is it incorrect if I do `session.save(n)` ? If it is not incorrect, then how do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do following things.These are:-

- Remove cascade option from news side.
- In your use case you have brand new news item and new user.Why you
  want to persist news item. Persist user object. Both will be persisted.
- In another use case where you have existing user and you want to add
  a new news item. In the service /dao implementation create a method
  for persisting the news object passing user id. Then you can use
  load/get to associate the use and persist the news item

Comment: So to explicitly answer the OP's question in the comment: `session.save(n)` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't need to set cascade in child side.  Simply have Cascade.ALL on parent side (User.news) should be enough.

One more thing, if you are going to delete news when user is deleted (as u mentioned in your post), I believe you need to add the cascade type Delete Orphan on parent side too.